# how sms are sent from twilio?

Tags: api, sms, twilio

I took Twilio just for an example, there are many companies which provides this kinda facility (sms API). Twilio supports sending sms in almost every country. I wanna know how do they do it at the core level, do they have any special access to the carriers protocol? For example: if I hit this url https://twilio.com/sms_api?number=xxxxx&text=hello (just for an example) it sends "hello" to the provided number(xxxxx). But how's this happening? do they have any special API provided by different carriers ?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, providers such as Twilio would have wholesale agreements with a mixture of partner SMS aggregators and mobile networks, mostly using [SMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Peer-to-Peer) and in some cases perhaps [SS7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signalling_System_No._7).

Since Twilio seems to offer voice service also, I think they're likely to have SS7 in the mix also, as SMPP isn't used for voice switching, but it's a convenient way to exchange high volumes of SMS traffic with mobile networks and SMS aggregators.

Answer (score 1):

man8 has got it with SMPP. But you can read a slightly more in depth [explanation from our messaging lead](http://twilio.com/blog/2016/04/where-do-text-messages-come-from.html), Ben Stein.

Particularly, the following section:

> How does a text message get from one phone to another phone?
>
> The protocol for SMS is called SMPP. Not to be confused with SMTP,
>   which is the mail protocol. SMPP is a store and forward protocol. The
>   way it will typically work is you have a client, the ESME (External
>   Short Messaging Entity), which is going to connect up to the server
>   which is the SMSC (Short Message Service Center). A persistent
>   connection is made between those two endpoints. Text messages and
>   other control commands flow bidirectionally: messages coming in,
>   messages going out, and something called delivery receipts, which tell
>   you the status of a message.
>
> It’s not necessarily an inelegant protocol, and it technically is
>   extensible, but you’re limited by adoption. In order to have this
>   lowest common denominator communication all around the world, you need
>   to use the features which are supported by all the servers and all of
>   the handsets.
>
> Generally, you’re limited in the protocol. For example, you want to
>   stick to 160 characters. There are neat features like concatenation,
>   where you can make messages much, much longer by concatenating them
>   together. However, that’s not supported by every handset by every
>   carrier. Especially when you look globally, support really varies. If
>   you want to keep that consistent user experience, you want to stay
>   lowest common denominator.